# SQL Server 2008 reports

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is SQL Server 2008 reports works in adobe reader 5.1?

How can i test that one?

What is Microsoft report viewer?

Comment: adobe reader 5.1? the current version is Adobe Reader 9.3

There are so many exploits that you are vulnerable to if using reader 5.1 please upgrade http://get.adobe.com/reader/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report viewer is the application that can view the reports.  There is a asp.net and WinForms version.  It can export to PDF which should would with 5.1  To test reports you will need to install the reporting service in SQL server.  There is a built in web editor if you don't have Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Kleinux,thanks for your reply.It means the reports which are build in sqlserver2008 can be viewed in report viewer. and it is compatible with adobe reader5.1.Is it correct?

Comment: I just tested saving a report as a PDF.  Mind you I don't have a copy of 5.1, but the properties window states it is PDF version 1.3 or Acrobat 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you replies.

I downloaded adobe reader version 5.0 from http://www.oldapps.com/adobe_reader.php?old_adobe=6?download
and tested it.It is working fine.